# How to transfer Apps using Samsung Switch?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-9, device-migration

I am trying to use Samsung's "Smart  Switch" to transfer apps from an old phone to a new phone (both Samsung S9's, both running Android v10). I followed the directions carefully but not all apps are *installed* on the new phone. In particular, apps I downloaded from the PlayStore were installed Ok, but none of my in-house-developed apps are installed. **Is this expected behavior?**

Notes:

1. All apps were successfully *transferred* (I see them when I tap "Apps") but they weren't *installed*. **Am I out-of-luck?**
2. I *can* manually install my apps using Android Developer Studio, but I have a lot of them and that would be a real pain.
3. I tried a "chatting" with Samsung tech support but they were clueless.
4. Interestingly, when I tried this a few days ago, I got messages saying that the apps were designed for an older version of Android and asked "Install Anyway?".  I always clicked YES but  they still were not installed. I no longer am asked this.

Comment: The Google device migration tool works the same way, apps from Play Store are re-downloaded, the rest ignored. Installing multiple apps is pretty easy if you have the APK files, just install them on comand-line via `adb install <app.apk>`. Even installing multiple APKs in one command is possible.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I CANNOT migrate non-Playstore apps using SmartSwitch (?).  I did try the "adb install" method and that DID work well.